# Deserialize a HashMap from XML using JAXB in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

This is my XML content:
I made it myself, so I can change it, just found this structure suitable for my data.

```
<root>
    <someProperty>prop</someProperty>
    <myObject>
        <someProperty2>prop2</someProperty3>
        <someProperty3>prop3</someProperty3>
        <mapping>
            <entry>
                <key>key1</key>
                <value>value1</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>key2</key>
                <value>value2</value>
            </entry>
        </mapping>
    </myObject>
    <myObject>
        <someProperty2>prop2</someProperty3>
        <someProperty3>prop3</someProperty3>
        <mapping>
            <entry>
                <key>key3</key>
                <value>value3</value>
            </entry>
        </mapping>
    </myObject>
</root>
```

What I want to achieve in terms of java classes is this:

```
Class 1:

class Root {
   String someProperty;
   List<MyObject> myObjects;
}

Class 2:

class MyObject {
   String someProperty2;
   String someProperty3;
   Map<String, String> mapping;
}
```

I'm kinda struggling to create XSD schema for my XML to do this deserialization right.
Basically I think I need a correct XSD schema so JAXB can properly generate Java classes.
So could you please provide an example of correct XSD schema for given XML?

Comment: Maybe chatgpt can help you.

Comment: I would do mapping element more of a list of entry elements, entry would contain two string properties (key / value) in XSD. But you wont have a Map in java generated code from that

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools for creating an XSD from a given XML (for example, there is one in Oxygen) but I wouldn't do it that way; it's an over-complex solution. A simpler approach these days is to convert the XML to JSON and then access the JSON from your Java code. Or with XSLT 3.0 you can bypass the JSON and convert the XML to maps and arrays which you can access directly from Java.